# How to detect mirror changes?

Tags: git

I am mirroring git repositories from one origin to another. The current script looks like the following:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://oldorigin
git fetch --all --tags
git remote update
git remote set-url origin ssh://neworigin
gh repo unarchive
git push --mirror
gh repo archive
```

I wouldn't want to unarchive repo if there were no changes. How can I check if `git push --mirror` will push anything? It is a new different origin.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but if you have two different places to pull/push to, then why not have two remotes? E.g. `origin` and `mirror` or something like that ...

Comment: I think no reason, I think `git fetch --all --target origin && git push --mirror mirror` should work. The script has to be stateful, `mirror` remote has to be added, so you have to check if it was added, if so add it. I found it's easier to `set` it.

Comment: Can't you just loop over all the refs with `git for-each-ref` and check if the target remote has the same commit hash for that reference?